# build a scrapy to load more and scrape the urls of the product in the page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi everyone i have a built a script in python using selenium to scroll infinite and click the load more button apparently it gives me only half of the products and also time consuming now i want to write a script in scrapy for the same to get all the product links in a csv file getting me all the links the script that i have written is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
with open('E:/grainger2.txt','r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    with open('E:/grainger11.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        headers = ("link,sublink")
        f.write(headers)
        f.write("\n")
        for dotnum in content:
            browser.get(dotnum)
            SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
            # Get scroll height
            last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            while True:
                # Scroll down to bottom
                browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                # Wait to load page
                time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
                # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
                new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                if new_height == last_height:
                    break
                last_height = new_height
            while True:
                try:
                    try:
                        loadMoreButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.list-view__load-more.list-view__load-more--js")
                        loadMoreButton.click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                    except NoSuchWindowException:
                        pass
                except Exception as e:
                    break

            try:
                try:
                    for links in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".list-view__product.list-view__product--js"):
                        aa = links.get_attribute("data-url-ie8")
                        print(aa)
                        ana = "loadlink"
                        f.write(ana+","+dotnum+","+aa+"\n")
                except NoSuchWindowException:
                    pass
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
```

The sample link for the same is : https://www.grainger.com/category/drill-bushings/machine-tool-accessories/machining/ecatalog/N-hg1?searchRedirect=products

using the above script i get only 200 product links but however the link contains  9748 products i want to extract all the link if someone could help me that would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating this more than you need to.

I suggest you use scrapy standalone (you dont need selenium) then use the hidden page links on the page to iterate through all the pages. Looking at the source...

```
<section class="searchControls paginator-control">
        <a
            href="/category/drill-bushings/machine-tool-accessories/machining/ecatalog/N-hg1?searchRedirect=products&requestedPage=2"
            class="btn list-view__load-more list-view__load-more--js"
            data-current-page="1"
            data-product-offset="32"
            data-total-products="9749"
            data-page-url="/category/drill-bushings/machine-tool-accessories/machining/ecatalog/N-hg1?searchRedirect=products"
            id="list-view__load-more--js">
            View More
        </a>
    </section>
```

Youll be able to write a pagination in Scrapy like this...

```
# go through the pagination links to access infinite scroll           
        next_page = response.css('div.paginator-control a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
          next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
          yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Id suggest you re-write this and use this pagination block to achieve the same result which would result in a more elequent solution.

To see a basic example see this [Scrapy information on following links](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links)

Comment: i am not able to implement that i am new in scrapy can you help me build the cript as the product is visible only when we scroll till that part